Can I get the compiler to use more efficient data layout here?
The following struct is 16 bytes on my setup:
struct MyExampleStruct
{
    double d;
    char b;
};

Due to the rule that the size of a struct is rounded up to the minimum alignment of it's largest member. The largest member having an alignment of 8, therefore it's rounded up to size of 16. If I add an int:
struct MyExampleStruct
{
    double d;
    char b;
    int i;
};

It's still 16 bytes. The char has alignment 1 and so goes at address 8. The int has alignment 4 and so goes at address 12, takes up four bytes, the result is 16 bytes, all the same. Now in the following:
struct ContainingStruct
{
    MyExampleStruct f;
    int i;
};

Now essentially what I would prefer is the same layout as I had in the previous example, however because alignment and padding rules are being applied in the same way, MyExampleStruct has a size of 16, the int goes at address 16, takes up 4 bytes, that's 20, however the rule is the size is rounded up to the alignment of the largest member, and so the size of ContainingStruct if 24. Can I get the compiler to be more efficient here or not?

FYI, alignment is a concept to make fetching easier for the processor.  If items in memory are not aligned, the processor may have to make additional fetches, thus taking more time to execute the code.  Some compilers may have specialized #pragma to handle packing of structures.  Note, these packing #pragma are not standard.

Re: "Due to the rule that the size of a struct is rounded up" -- that's not a C++ rule; it's a compiler behavior. To figure out how to change it you need to specify what compiler you're using and what the target hardware is.

Which compiler are you using?  Depending on how you use #pragma pack containing struct can vary from 13 to 32 bytes.

@ThomasMatthews on some processors, unaligned memory access will fault with a SIGBUS signal and will terminate the process if left unhandled. So it's not just performance loss. It could be fatal.

Aside from using compiler-specific pragmas (#pragma pack() for gcc), if the object becomes a non-standard layout, and it inherits the object instead of containing it, then the compiler is allowed to cram its members in there.
struct Empty {};
struct MyExampleStruct: public Empty
{
    double d;    
    char b;
};

struct ContainingStruct: public MyExampleStruct
{
    int i;
};

Both objects have size of 16, also having a destructor or a virtual table counts as being non-standard layout.
godbolt demo

Only clang and gcc do this optimization, but not MSVC, it breaks the ABI so you cannot pass this object as a C struct.
using #pragma pack(4) would be more portable as it is supported by all of MSVC, gcc and clang.

I wonder why the downvote.

@Zebrafish I have upvoted you back. This stack overflow downvoting culture is very toxic, so just don't let it touch you. Get -1000 if needed, just get the answer you need

@Zebrafish Btw, always follow these two rules of thumb: 1. Put the most frequently accessed data members on top so that only one cache line needs to be fetched when accessing them and 2. order your data members from the biggest to the smallest, that will minimize your padding.

@lobelk You should have at least the bare minimum understanding of something you are criticizing. Also, you should not do anything you want at the expense of everyone else.
